# Angular4 - Sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, angular, web-services, visual-studio-code

I am developing an application in VS code, and I want to export data received from web service into SQL server. I am aware of mssql extension that links between VS code and SQL studio, but not sure where to start..

An example or related articles would be wonderful.

Thanks

**data from web service**

```
getData(res, name: String ){

    this.arrLN = [];
    this.arrLN.push(data0].LastValue,
    res[data1].LastValue,
    res[data2].FinalValue,

    res[data3].LastValue,
    res[data4].FinalValue,


    }
```

Comment: You receive the data in your code and then use an insert to put it in the database.

Comment: i'll update my code to make my question clear.. would you please take a look?

Comment: First comes to mind to separate Front & Back end cleanly and use REST to let them exchange data. These articles might be a starting point if you have more detailed questions about going this way feel free to ask:

https://www.genuitec.com/connecting-angular-2-app-java-ee-backend/
http://javaee.ch/2017/04/06/java-angular-demo/

Comment: my question is simply... how do I transfer data I received in angular code then to db...